# How to transform y-axis values of Google Earth Engine chart?

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

I'm using `Chart.image.series()` in Google Earth Engine to create a line chart with two series from an image collection of processed land cover data (two binary bands per year: grass/shrub/wetland, and cropland/developed) and a region (10 mi radius circle).

I would like the y-axis values (sum area) to be log transformed but I can't figure out how to do that. Such as if `ee.Reducer.sum().log()` was allowed.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c08b3d0316375648af0fe1cd4fe8128a

```
//try to calculate landcover rate of change for cropland/developed and grass/shrub/wetlands


//Get CDL, and point of interest
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("USDA/NASS/CDL")
var geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([-100.12247612030984, 46.13719639996092]);
var mi10 = geometry.buffer(16093.4);

Map.centerObject(mi10, 10);

var ic= imageCollection.filterDate('2008', '2019');
//print(ic);

//get grass, shrub, wetlands
//other hay non-alfalfa 37, shrubland 64, 152, wetlands 87,  190, 195, grass 176 
//get crop and development
// crop 1-36, 38-61, 66-77, 82, 204-254, devleoped 121-124
var gogetit = function(image){
  var cropland = image.select('cropland');
  
  var total = cropland.eq(37).or(cropland.eq(64)).or(cropland.eq(152))
  .or(cropland.eq(87)).or(cropland.eq(195)).or(cropland.eq(190)).or(cropland.eq(176));
  
  var cropdev = cropland.gte(1).and(cropland.lte(36))
  .or(cropland.gte(38).and(cropland.lte(61)))
  .or(cropland.gte(66).and(cropland.lte(77))).or(cropland.eq(82))
  .or(cropland.gte(121).and(cropland.lte(124)))
  .or(cropland.gte(204).and(cropland.lte(254)));
  
  var total_fm = total.focal_mode(75, 'square', 'meters');
  var cropdev_fm = cropdev.focal_mode(75, 'square', 'meters');
  
  return total_fm.addBands(cropdev_fm).rename(['grass/shrub/wetland', 'crop/developed'])
  .set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
};
var ic2 = ic.map(gogetit);
print(ic2)

var crop08 = ic2.first().select('crop/developed');
var grass18 = ee.Image(ic2.filterMetadata('system:index', 'equals', '2018').first());
var grass18 = grass18.select('grass/shrub/wetland');
var grass08 = ic2.first().select('grass/shrub/wetland');
Map.addLayer(crop08.updateMask(crop08),{palette:['yellow']}, 'crop08')
Map.addLayer(grass08.updateMask(grass08),{palette:['red']}, 'grass08')
Map.addLayer(grass18.updateMask(grass18),{palette:['green']}, 'grass18')
Map.addLayer(mi10, {}, 'area');

//convert to area
var prep = function(image){
return image.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
};
var ic2 = ic2.map(prep);
//print(ic2);

//line chart for two landcovers with trendlines
var chartit = new ui.Chart.image.series(ic2, mi10, ee.Reducer.sum(), 30)
.setOptions({
      title: 'Grass/Shrub/Wetland vs. Crop/Developed',
      hAxis: {'title': 'Year'},
      vAxis: {'title': 'Area'},
      trendlines: { 0: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true} , 
                    1: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true}}
                    });
print(chartit);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the `reduceRegion` outside of the chart reduction, which allows you to log transform the values. Set the log values as properties of the images and then you can chart them using the `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature` function. Here is the code you need to add to your script:

```js
// Define a function to perform log transformation of region reduction results.
function logTransformation(img){
  // Reduce region (sum).
  var imgDict = img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: mi10,
    scale: 30
  });

  // Get the bands and values from the reduce region dictionary.
  var keys = imgDict.keys();
  var vals = imgDict.values();

  // Map over the values and transform to log.
  var valsLog = vals.map(function(val){
    return ee.Number(val).log();
  });

  // Make a dictionary from the band anmes and new log values.
  var imgDictLog = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, valsLog);

  // Return image with properties set from the band names and log transformations.
  return img.set(imgDictLog);
}

// Apply region reduction and log transformation.
var ic2Reduced = ic2.map(logTransformation);

// Line chart for two landcovers with trendlines
var chartLog = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(
  ic2Reduced,
  'system:time_start',
  ['crop/developed', 'grass/shrub/wetland']
)
.setOptions({
      title: 'Grass/Shrub/Wetland vs. Crop/Developed',
      hAxis: {'title': 'Year'},
      vAxis: {'title': 'Area'},
      trendlines: { 0: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true} , 
                    1: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true}}
                    });

print(chartLog);
```

Here is the modified script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7b1f46cad813cccc45e4b265a7f4e7ba